# How to stress/load testing in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, stress-testing

I am creating a ecommerce website in magento. I want to use stress testing on my website to see How robust is my website and how much load it can bear. I have gone through a lot of stuff for that but I could not find something satisfactory. Please suggest me some tools for doing that and can i do it on localhost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**jmeter**](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), [**apache bench**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), [**siege**](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to load test your website.

Try increasing the load on your server with these tools. And find the maximum number of clients that your application can handle. Then increase more load to see how more it can take before it breaks.

Recently I did some load testing on a streaming server with flazr. Server were working fine till `400` concurrent connection. After `400` it starts to become slow and when its `450` it breaks. So 400 was the maximum number of connection it supports.  But if its near 450 I'll try to decrease load to save my server or increase the hardware capacity like RAM, CPU, NIC

Some links might be usefull

1. [Bench-marking site performance with apachebench](https://techcommons.stanford.edu/topics/web-development/benchmarking-site-performance-apachebench)
2. [Simple is Hard](http://talks.php.net/show/froscon08) a siege is being used by Rasmus Lerdorf on a Talk
3. SQA.SE answer on [where can I find good jmeter tutorials](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials)

Comment: Thanks! Nice answer! Following it!

Comment: Out of these three tools, what will you suggest?

Comment: I used jmeter and siege. JMeter is best in my opinion. But it'll be little harder to grasp first time. It has a UI so you dont need to learn a lot of commands options like `ab` or `siege`

Comment: @MJQ I have added some tutorial links for you.

Comment: Dont know. Never checked that way. JMeter is quite standard for load testing in QA community.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jmeter to test load and performace of the Magento website. Jmeter is good validator tool and generate quit efficient analysis report. Jmeter is quit useful for small and medium business to test website load and performance and it is free from any license.